# White patches around Custom Button

Tags: blackberry

i am having a screen on which i have painted a image  as a background and i am placing 6 custom buttons in a verticalfield manager, every thing is working fine , but when focus comes on the last custom button, then it is surrounded by a white patch.. i don't no what the problem is...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fix usually works for that white background around custom fields.  Override the `moveFocus` method to do the following:

```
protected int moveFocus(int amount, int status, int time) {
    int val = super.moveFocus(amount, status, time);
    invalidate();
    return val;
}
```